# does it make sense to define const scope_refptr()?

Tags: c++, chromium

```
scoped_refptr<any_class> a_scoped_refptr;
const scoped_refptr<any_class> something = a_scoped_refptr; // Compile error.
```

If it's const than we can not modify the ref_counter, but I want to imply that the content that the pointer points to should not be changed, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, you did not mention the compiler error, but I'm guessing it's a simple syntax error because you didn't specify a variable name for the `scoped_refptr`.

Secondly, if you want a pointer to a const object, specify that as the pointer type. So try:

```
scoped_refptr<any_class const> myPointer = a_scoped_refptr;
```

Comment: thanks, does scoped_refptr<const any_class> myPointer = a_scoped_refptr; has any different with scoped_refptr<any_class const> myPointer = a_scoped_refptr;?

Comment: No; it's the same. `const mytype` is just a C++ convenience syntax for the more "proper" `mytype const`.